# Unable to clone the repository from server PC to remote PC using bitvise SSH

Tags: git, ssh

I am trying to make the clone of one repository made in server PC in D folder named Repository such that path is

> D:/Repository

and then I made repo over there by doing right click and select git bash and do the following command

> git init

Now this will make Repository.

I am connecting from remote PC using Bitvise SSH . 
When I tried the following command:

> git clone ssh://rsehdev@10.135.156.240:/~/d/Repository/.git

it will print this error:

> fatal: '~/d/Repository/.git' does not appear to be a git repository
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I already set path in ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE regarding git.

Any other suggestion for doing this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding how windows file systems and unix-based file systems are laid out.  I'm not sure what `D:/` is but it should be `D:\`.  Moving on, ~/ indicates your home directory (for your username) on unix but your specified path doesn't seem to mention anything about a home directory.  Are you on a unix or linux machine?  Ensure that your git clone path is pointing to the correct location on the machine.  Also, it seems like you want a path like `ssh://rsehdev@10.135.156.240:<path>/myrepository.git`, not `ssh://rsehdev@10.135.156.240:<path>/myrepository/myrepository.git`, according to an example like https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Comment: <path>  in the above link that you mentioned is D:/ directory only in my case.

Comment: it seems like you are ignoring the important details of my post